# Jenkins Chromium Browser And ChromeDriver Versions Not Matching Even After Update

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am running automated tests on a Jenkins server and the chromium-browser and Chromedriver versions have become mismatched as chromium-browser auto updated itself. I now receive the following warning

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only 
supports Chrome version 86
Current browser version is 89.0.4389.82 with binary path /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

I have updated the Chromedriver to 89 to match the browser. But when I run the Jenkins workspace with my tests, I still receive the same error message. It is not seeing my updated Chromedriver version or maybe the old version is cached still on Jenkins.

Here is my output showing the versions on the Jenkins server

```
jenkins$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch- 
heads/4389@{#294})
jenkins$ chromium-browser --product-version
89.0.4389.82
```

So they are matching for sure and in the correct location.
Does anyone have any idea of what needs to be done to finish off the update to get the versions matched when I run my tests on Jenkins?

Comment: Check your code and see whether you are pointing to correct chrome driver

Comment: Which library you use for the web driver managment (to automaticly align browser and webdriver versions)?

Comment: @GajJulije I don't have a web driver manager set up.

Comment: @JackGruber try with https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager if you are using java, if no let me know what you are using

Comment: @GajJulije Robot framework and Python.

Comment: Try auto updete with this https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/ for Py